# What is "lambda binding" in Python?

Tags: python, binding, lambda

I understand what are lambda functions in Python, but I can't find what is the meaning of "lambda binding" by searching the Python docs.
A link to read about it would be great.
A trivial explained example would be even better.
Thank you.

Comment: As far as I can tell, "lambda binding" isn't real terminology. Aside from some minor implementation details, functions created by `lambda` aren't special; they just are restricted in what they can do. You can still pass them around and use them like ordinary functions. It's *names* that get bound, and we specifically are interested in names *from an enclosing scope* (such as the global scope).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First, a general definition:

> When a program or function statement
>   is executed, the current values of
>   formal parameters are saved (on the
>   stack) and within the scope of the
>   statement, they are bound to the
>   values of the actual arguments made in
>   the call. When the statement is
>   exited, the original values of those
>   formal arguments are restored. This
>   protocol is fully recursive. If within
>   the body of a statement, something is
>   done that causes the formal parameters
>   to be bound again, to new values, the
>   lambda-binding scheme guarantees that
>   this will all happen in an orderly
>   manner.

Now, there is an excellent [python example in a discussion here](http://markmail.org/message/fypalne4rp5curta):

"...there is only one binding for `x`: doing `x = 7` just changes the value in the pre-existing binding. That's why

```
def foo(x): 
   a = lambda: x 
   x = 7 
   b = lambda: x 
   return a,b
```

returns two functions that both return 7; if there was a new binding after the `x = 7`, the functions would return different values [assuming you don't call foo(7), of course. Also assuming nested_scopes]...."

Comment: Is this definition quoted from somewhere?

Answer (score 8):

I've never heard that term, but one explanation could be the "default parameter" hack used to assign a value directly to a lambda's parameter. Using Swati's example:

```
def foo(x): 
    a = lambda x=x: x 
    x = 7 
    b = lambda: x 
    return a,b

aa, bb = foo(4)
aa() # Prints 4
bb() # Prints 7
```

Answer (score 1):

Where have you seen the phrase used?

"Binding" in Python generally refers to the process by which a variable name ends up pointing to a specific object, whether by assignment or parameter passing or some other means, e.g.:

```
a = dict(foo="bar", zip="zap", zig="zag") # binds a to a newly-created dict object
b = a # binds b to that same dictionary

def crunch(param):
  print param

crunch(a) # binds the parameter "param" in the function crunch to that same dict again
```

So I would guess that "lambda binding" refers to the process of binding a lambda function to a variable name, or maybe binding its named parameters to specific objects?  There's a pretty good explanation of binding in the Language Reference, at http://docs.python.org/ref/naming.html