# Why does the following code always output 16?

Tags: python

```
def makeActions():
    acts=[]
    for i in range(5):
        print len(acts)
        acts.append(lambda x: i ** x)
        print acts[i]
    return acts
acts=makeActions()
for i in range(5):
    print acts[i](2)
```

Output:

```
16
16
16
16
16
```

Expected output:

```
0
1
4
9
16
```

Comment: Because that's what the code says to do, maybe? You would have to clarify what you expected, then someone could try to tell you what you did wrong.

Comment: I don't know how `16` comes out...

Comment: I've edited your question to give you an idea how to improve them in the future :-)

Answer (score 22):

Because the `i` in the lambda is probably not what you expect. To verify this, change the code:

```
acts.append(lambda x: (i, i ** x))
```

Now the `print` tells you the value of `i`:

```
(4, 16)
(4, 16)
(4, 16)
(4, 16)
(4, 16)
```

This means that the `lambda` doesn't copy the value of `i` but keeps a reference to the variable, so all `lambda`s see the same value. To fix this, copy `i`:

```
acts.append(lambda x, i=i: (i, i ** x))
```

The little `i=i` creates a local copy of `i` inside the `lambda`.

[EDIT] Now why is this? In the versions of Python before 2.1, local functions (i.e. functions defined inside of other functions) couldn't see the variables in the same scope.

```
def makeActions():
    acts=[]
    for i in range(5):
        print len(acts)
        def f(x):   # <-- Define local function
            return i ** x
        acts.append(f)
        print acts[i]
    return acts
```

then you'd get an error that `i` isn't defined. `lambda` could see the enclosing scope at the cost of a somewhat wierd syntax.

This behavior has been fixed in one of the recent versions of Python (2.5, IIRC). With these old versions of Python, you'd have to write:

```
        def f(x, i=i):   # <-- Must copy i
            return i ** x
```

Since the fix (see [PEP 3104](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3104/)), `f()` can see variables in the same scope, so `lambda` isn't necessary anymore.

Comment: Whoa. So why i in the first example is always 4? Isnt it natural to make local copy when lambda is created? Now its making copy as well but in strange place.

Comment: Because the first lambda gets a reference to the loop variable `i`. In fact the `i` in the lambda code is the very same `i` in the `for`. As the loop variable changes, all the references to it change as well. When you say `i=i` in a function/lambda definition, then you say: Create a new parameter and initialize it with the current value of the loop variable `i`.

Comment: +1 just for having fixed the bad question with actual and expected output.

Answer (score 6):

Because all lambda functions you create are bound to i, which becomes 4 at the end of loop, and as we all well know 4*4 = 16

to avoid that create your functions using nested function(closure) e.g.

```
def makePowerFunc(base):
    def powerFunc(x):
        return base**x
    return powerFunc

def makeActions():
    acts=[]
    for i in range(5):
        acts.append(makePowerFunc(i))

    return acts
acts=makeActions()
for i in range(5):
print acts[i](2)
```

**output:**

```
0
1
4
9
16
```

There are other ways to solve it, but it is better to have a named nested function instead of lambda, and you can do many more things with such closures

Answer (score 5):

It's counterintuitive or at least less common syntax. I guess you meant:

```
acts.append(lambda x, i = i: i ** x)
```

which will output:

```
0
1
4
9
16
```

---

fn. in your version,

```
acts.append(lambda x, i: i ** x)
```

the lambda functions were created, but they all referenced the local `i` from the loop, which stopped at `i = 4`, so all your lambdas were saying: `lambda x: 4 ** x`, hence

```
for i in range(5):
    print acts[i](2)
```

would print all 16s.

---

ffn. a blog post about broken lambda: http://math.andrej.com/2009/04/09/pythons-lambda-is-broken/

Answer (score 3):

This phenomena is called lambda binding see [What is "lambda binding" in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160859/what-is-lambda-binding-in-python)