# How to create one dictionary with functions printing their names as value

Tags: python, lambda

Suppose I have a list of string `['a', 'b', 'c']`. I want to generate one dictionary with the element in that list (`'a'`, `'b'` and `'c'`) as key, and a function which prints the key as the value (`print('a')`, `print('b')`, `print('c')`).

I tried this code:

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'c']
m = {k: (lambda: print(k)) for k in l}
```

But the result is not right:

```
m['a']()
c
m['b']()
c
```

If I call the functions directly, like `m = {k: print(k) for k in l}`, the output is correct (although the dictionary does not store the right values).

Why doesn't it work with the `lambda`s?

Comment: @josh-lee you are right. But it seems the answers are different.

Answer (score 3):

The reason you're getting `c` as the output for each key is because the `c` comes last in the iteration, so the final value of `x` is `c` here, and your program can be expanded as follows:

```
    for x in lis:
        def func():
            print(x)
        dic[x]=func
```

Here your function is actually accessing the value of a global variable `x`, not a local variable. And as at the end of iteration `x` is `c`, you get `c` as answer.

Therefore you need to use default arguments to store the value in a local variable.

correct code:

```
    In [2]: lis=['a', 'b', 'c']

    In [3]: dic={x:lambda i=x:print(i) for x in lis}

    In [4]: dic['a']
    Out[4]: <function __main__.<lambda>>

    In [5]: dic['a']()
    a
    In [6]: dic['b']()
    b
```

or:

```
In [16]: for x in lis:
    def func(i=x):
        print(i)    
    dic[x]=func
   ....:     

In [17]: dic['b']()
b
```

Comment: You might want to explain this one, it's one of those really non-obvious ones.

Comment: Thanks @ashwini-chaudhary, and please explain this. I don't understand why this works.

Comment: doesn't seem to work in python 2.7

Comment: @WenbinWu added some explanation.

Answer (score 2):

The basic problem you encounter has to do with the binding of the labda expression and you can find several questions in that direction (e.g. [What is "lambda binding" in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160859/what-is-lambda-binding-in-python) or [Python lambda's binding to local values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10452770/python-lambdas-binding-to-local-values))

A common solution is to use [`functools.partial`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to avoid the problem:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import functools

l = ['a', 'b', 'c']
m = {k: functools.partial(print, k) for k in l}
```