# In Python, why do lambdas in list comprehensions overwrite themselves in retrospect?

Tags: python, list, function, lambda, list-comprehension

Consider the following code:

```
def f (a):
    return 1
def g (a):
    return 2

[lambda a: i(a) for i in (f,g)][0](0)
```

The result is 2. Where it should clearly be 1! I would expect this code to execute as follows. Create a list. Copy the function f into the first index. Copy g into the second index. Fin.

Why does this execute the way it does?!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The lambda didn't overwrite itself, it is `i` that was overwritten.  This is a common mistake regarding variable scopes.  Try this:

```
[lambda a, i=i: i(a) for i in (f,g)][0](0)
```

(the difference is binding the value of `i` at the time the lambda is created)

See also:

- [Weird behavior: Lambda inside list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7368522/1172714)
- [What is “lambda binding” in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/160898/1172714)
- [Python lambda's binding to local values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10452770/1172714)

Answer (score 1):

I'll expand slightly on @dsh's answer.

When the list comprehension expression

```
[lambda a: i(a) for i in (f,g)]
```

is evaluated, it creates two anonymous functions, each of which to the effect of

```
def _______(a):
    return i(a)
```

However, after the evaluation of the above list comprehension, the name `i` is bound to its last iteration value, which is the object bound to `g`, i.e. 2nd of your functions.

Now, **after that**, when one of the anonymous functions in the list gets called, it accesses the name `i`, which is in the module-global scope and **bound to the same thing as `g` is**.

---

Edit: oh, @dsh's expanded it too.